# Switching pools in azure pipeline based on a variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an azure pipeline that runs in a main repo and also a fork. For the main repo I want to use a self hosted agent but in the form I want to use a hosted one. I have tried using variables defined in a library and also in the pipeline itself but both of these appear to be compiled at runtime.

Is there any way to set compile time variables so that I can add this sort of if statement to my yaml?

```
  - job: 'Build'
    displayName: 'Build job'
    pool:
      ${{ if eq(variables.isFork, true) }}:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest' # Use a Microsoft-hosted agent for the fork
      ${{ if ne(variables.isFork, true) }}:
        name: $(poolName)  # Variable for the pool name
        demands:
          - Agent.Name -equals $(agentDemand)
```

I know I can set it so that the pipeline requests which one to use:

```
parameters:
- name: poolType
  displayName: 'Select Pool Type'
  type: string
  default: 'hosted'
  values:
  - hosted
  - self-hosted

jobs:
- job: ExampleJob
  ${{ if eq(parameters.poolType, 'hosted') }}:
    - template: pool-hosted.yml
  ${{ if eq(parameters.poolType, 'self-hosted') }}:
    - template: pool-self-hosted.yml
```

but I would really prefer to automate the whole process based on the azure project running the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an an example on how you could choose a specific agent-pool based on the Azure DevOps project-name.

In this example I am using the MS-hosted as the default option if no matches in the if-statements for the project-name(s):

```yaml
# agentpool-example.yaml

jobs:

- job: Build
  displayName: Build job
  ${{ if eq(variables['System.TeamProject'], 'NameOfMyProject1') }}:
    pool: name-of-my-agentpool1
  ${{ elseif eq(variables['System.TeamProject'], 'NameOfMyProject2') }}:
    pool: name-of-my-agentpool2    
  ${{ else }}:
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
  
  # Just some output to confirm
  - pwsh: |
      Write-Output "$(Agent.MachineName)"
      Write-Output "$(System.TeamProject)"
```

I think based on this example you should be able to reach full automation for the whole process.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the main repository is named "**MyRepo**", you can name the fork repository "**MyRepo.fork**" or any of other names that are different from the main repository.

1. If the pipeline is directly triggered by the main repository or fork repository, not triggered by the PR from the fork repository, you can set the conditional like as below in the YAML pipeline.

   ```yaml
   jobs:
   - job: Build
     displayName: 'Build job'
     ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'MyRepo') }}:
       pool:
         name: $(poolName)
         demands: Agent.Name -equals $(agentDemand)
     ${{ elseif eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'MyRepo.fork') }}:
       pool:
         vmImage: windows-latest
     steps:
     . . .
   ```

   By this way, when the pipeline is directly triggered by the main repository, it will use the self-hosted agent. When pipeline is triggered by the fork repository, it will use the Microsoft-hosted agent.
2. If the pipeline is triggered by the PR from the fork repository to the main repository, you can set the conditional like as below in the YAML pipeline.

   ```yaml
   jobs:
   - job: Build
     displayName: 'Build job'
     ${{ if eq(variables['System.PullRequest.IsFork'], True) }}:
       pool:
         vmImage: windows-latest
     ${{ else }}:
       pool:
         name: $(poolName)
         demands: Agent.Name -equals $(agentDemand)
     steps:
     . . .
   ```

   By this way, when the pipeline is triggered by the PR from the fork repository to the main repository, it will use the Microsoft-hosted agent. Otherwise, it will use the self-hosted agent.

You can find the related predefined variables in "[**Use predefined variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)".

---

Comment: In my above answer, I have shared the methods to use the pipeline predefined variables **`Build.Repository.Name`** and **`System.PullRequest.IsFork`** to check if the pipeline is triggered by the fork repository or the PR from the fork repository. Have you tried the methods. Are they working for you? @GrahamJRoy